# getting error Error MSB3644 in Rider on mac

Tags: jetbrains-rider, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm using the react preview template for Visual studio on my macbook air, os 14.2. I have visual studio community for mac installed as well; the application builds and runs fine on visual studio with the caveat that the web api runs, but the client react app does not start. I'm not too concerned with that issue now. The issue is that I cannot build the same application in Rider-I get Error MSB3644 when I try and build it.